# Elasticsearch stems words end with symbols/special character

Tags: elasticsearch, searchkick

I use a `whitespace` tokenizer, with `searchkick_stemmer`

"company" -> "compani"

"company+" -> "company+"

how can I make "company+" to be "compani+" or ["compani","+"]

I've tried with edge-gram, works fine, but it generated too many tokens.
I'm considering if there is another approach, like conditional scripting or else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this example but recommend read [pattern token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern_replace-tokenfilter.html)

```
POST _analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "filter": [
    "stemmer"
  ],
  "char_filter": {
    "type": "pattern_replace",
    "pattern": "[+]",
    "replacement": " $0"
  },
  "text": [
    "company+"
  ]
}
```

Tokens:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "compani",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 7,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "+",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 8,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Btw, it's a silly question, how can I remove back the token '+', because after stem, I've produced the desired tokens `compani+`.